# SAPUI5 request timeout to the Gateway

Tags: sapui5, sap-gateway

I have an odata-request in my SAPUI5 application which calls the Gateway.
On the Gateway, I have an Trusted RFC connection to the backend.

Now I have a complex algorithm with a duration around 2 minutes.

After 60 seconds, I get an timeout error.

`HTTP request failed500,Internal Server Error,500 Connection timed out`

Is there a opportunity to increase the timeout?

I tried it with the parameters `gw/reg_timeout` `gw/conn_pending` and with the keepalive-timeout of the rfc connection.

All this options haven´t solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you already tried everything from [SAP Help](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73ehp1/helpdata/en/48/ad5afa8bc96744e10000000a421937/content.htm).
Maybe this is some [ICM/WebDispatcher timeout](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73/helpdata/de/48/88b52977323cb8e10000000a42189d/content.htm), check the link and try some of the settings, i.e. PROCTIMEOUT. And also consider the hints there:

> **Recommendation**
>
> In systems where the standard timeout setting of **60**
>   seconds for the keep-alive and processing timeouts is not sufficient
>   due to long-running applications, SAP recommends that both the **TIMEOUT**
>   and **PROCTIMEOUT** parameters are set for the services concerned so that
>   they can be configured independently of each other. The **TIMEOUT** value
>   should not be set unnecessarily high. We recommend you set this
>   parameter as follows:
>
> **icm/server_port_0 = PROT=HTTP,PORT=1080,TIMEOUT=60,PROCTIMEOUT=600**
>
> in order to allow a
>   maximum processing time of 10 minutes.